# What is the reason behind why the added column to my data frame in R is of a "list" form instead of a data type? and how to rectify?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm doing some practice exercises with respect to regression analysis in R. One of the questions asks me to perform some simple analysis using a linear regression function. To document the intermediate steps, I added the values to a preloaded data set which is what the following screen grab is:

[image]

The columns `GPA` and `ACT_Score` came preloaded with the data set. The following is the code I used to add the `fitted_GPA` column:

```
> GPA_lm = lm(formula = GPA ~ ACT_Score, data = ch_1_exer_119_GPA)
> fitted_GPA = coef(GPA_lm)[[1]] + coef(GPA_lm)[[2]]*ch_1_exer_119_GPA[,2]   # created vector of fitted values
> ch_1_exer_119_GPA$fitted_GPA = fitted_GPA       # added column of fitted values to data frame
```

So now when I got to examine the type of my new column compared to one of the preloaded columns I have the following observation

```
> typeof(ch_1_exer_119_GPA$fitted_GPA)  #added column to data frame
[1] "list"
> typeof(ch_1_exer_119_GPA$GPA)  #preloaded column to data frame
[1] "double"
```

This came up when I was entering the name of one of the created columns for another calculation and noticed that the icon in front of the variable was not a "purple tag" like the variables that came loaded with the data set, but instead had the "data frame" icon.

This didn't have a direct effect on any of the simple calculations I did, but I can envision something like this presenting a problem in the future when I'm dealing with more complex scenarios. So I'd like to get an understanding as to what it is that I did to create this and how to rectify it?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: As requested from r2evans the following output:

```
> dput(head(ch_1_exer_119_GPA,15))
structure(list(GPA = c(3.897, 3.885, 3.778, 2.54, 3.028, 3.865, 
2.962, 3.961, 0.5, 3.178, 3.31, 3.538, 3.083, 3.013, 3.245), 
    ACT_Score = c(21, 14, 28, 22, 21, 31, 32, 27, 29, 26, 24, 
    30, 24, 24, 33), fitted_GPA = structure(list(ACT_Score = c(2.92941895227791, 
    2.65762906394109, 3.20120884061472, 2.96824607918317, 2.92941895227791, 
    3.3176902213305, 3.35651734823576, 3.16238171370946, 3.24003596751998, 
    3.1235545868042, 3.04590033299369, 3.27886309442524, 3.04590033299369, 
    3.04590033299369, 3.39534447514102)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -15L)), residuals_GPA = structure(list(ACT_Score = c(0.967581047722093, 
    1.22737093605891, 0.576791159385276, -0.428246079183166, 
    0.0985810477220932, 0.547309778669498, -0.394517348235762, 
    0.798618286290536, -2.74003596751998, 0.0544454131957952, 
    0.264099667006314, 0.259136905574757, 0.0370996670063146, 
    -0.0329003329936857, -0.150344475141022)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -15L))), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: We can't really test with an image of your data, please post the output from `dput(head(ch_1_exer_119_GPA,15))`.

Comment: By chance, is this a dataset built into R or is it outside? If so, could you add a ```dput()``` of your data so we can recreate it? You can also use ```dput(head(x))``` to share just a few entries.

Comment: What does this output assist you in doing? Just curious to understand more so I can diagnose things.

Comment: @AcidCatfish, the data set is outside of R

Comment: @dc3rd The output from ```dput()``` will give us a line of code which will create the dataset in R. Essentially, you will be sharing the data with us in a reproducible way with out having to share an actual file. Right now, there isn't an easy way for us to recreate your data in R since we only have an image of the data. We need to be able to recreate the problem and see step-by-step what is happening in order to help you.

Comment: Ah. I see....Well form this output. The other thing I could mention is that the data set came from a simple text file of two columns.

Comment: Without having data to work with, I'll just go based off of my previous experience: often times R will have functions which automatically convert from one type to another. You may need to specify as part of your arguments in your functions which data type you want a column to be in. I haven't had to work with type double, but you can use ```as.double()``` to convert. List is a configuration of data as well. You can unlist the column into a vector and add it back to the dataframe as an integer column. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: This actually probably explains precisely what I was thinking was occurring, but was dubious as to if R would take the liberty to convert the vector itself. I guess I was hoping for things to be done for me instead of having to manually do it. No big issue. Have to go review how to unlist a column and add it back as an integer column. Thanks

Comment: @dc3rd You don't always have to go and do thing manually and often there are very simple functions which can be passed as arguments to avoid this from happening. Luckily people have provided you examples of fixes though.

Comment: I agree @AcidCatfish , i am more of the viewpoint of since I am in the nascent stages of learning the art form, I wanted to understand the fundamentals and how things work before allowing myself to just use the magic of all of the functions....possibly a masochistic approach I know. but brings me peace. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, what is happening is that in

```r
fitted_GPA = coef(GPA_lm)[[1]] + coef(GPA_lm)[[2]]*ch_1_exer_119_GPA[,2]   # created vector of fitted values
```

the resulting object `fitted_GPA` is a dataframe with one variable and not a vector. Behind the scenes, "a data frame is a list of equal-length vectors"

If you replace the above line with

```r
fitted_GPA = coef(GPA_lm)[[1]] + coef(GPA_lm)[[2]] * ch_1_exer_119_GPA$ACT_Score   # created vector of fitted values
```

you will get a vector instead of a data frame, so that when adding the new variable to your data frame with

```r
ch_1_exer_119_GPA$fitted_GPA = fitted_GPA
```

it works as expected.

### Edit: Full Reprex

Here the whole script, indeed the output in the console "looks like" that the rows are `<dbl>` vectors, but `glimpse()` shows that the column is actually a `data.frame`.

```r
library(dplyr)

ch_1_exer_119_GPA <- structure(list(GPA = c(3.897, 3.885, 3.778, 2.54, 3.028, 3.865,  2.962, 3.961, 0.5, 3.178, 3.31, 3.538, 3.083, 3.013, 3.245), 
                                    ACT_Score = c(21, 14, 28, 22, 21, 31, 32, 27, 29, 26, 24,30, 24, 24, 33),
                                    fitted_GPA = structure(list(
                                      ACT_Score = c(2.92941895227791, 2.65762906394109, 3.20120884061472, 2.96824607918317,
                                                    2.92941895227791, 3.3176902213305, 3.35651734823576, 3.16238171370946,
                                                    3.24003596751998, 3.1235545868042, 3.04590033299369, 3.27886309442524,
                                                    3.04590033299369, 3.04590033299369, 3.39534447514102)), 
                                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L)),
                                    residuals_GPA = structure(list(ACT_Score = c(0.967581047722093, 1.22737093605891, 0.576791159385276,
                                                                                 -0.428246079183166, 0.0985810477220932, 0.547309778669498,
                                                                                 -0.394517348235762, 0.798618286290536, -2.74003596751998,
                                                                                 0.0544454131957952, 0.264099667006314, 0.259136905574757,
                                                                                 0.0370996670063146,  -0.0329003329936857, -0.150344475141022)),
                                                              class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-15L))), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
ch_1_exer_119_GPA
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>      GPA ACT_Score fitted_GPA$ACT_Score residuals_GPA$ACT_Score
#>    <dbl>     <dbl>                <dbl>                   <dbl>
#>  1  3.90        21                 2.93                  0.968 
#>  2  3.88        14                 2.66                  1.23  
#>  3  3.78        28                 3.20                  0.577 
#>  4  2.54        22                 2.97                 -0.428 
#>  5  3.03        21                 2.93                  0.0986
#>  6  3.86        31                 3.32                  0.547 
#>  7  2.96        32                 3.36                 -0.395 
#>  8  3.96        27                 3.16                  0.799 
#>  9  0.5         29                 3.24                 -2.74  
#> 10  3.18        26                 3.12                  0.0544
#> 11  3.31        24                 3.05                  0.264 
#> 12  3.54        30                 3.28                  0.259 
#> 13  3.08        24                 3.05                  0.0371
#> 14  3.01        24                 3.05                 -0.0329
#> 15  3.24        33                 3.40                 -0.150

glimpse(ch_1_exer_119_GPA)
#> Rows: 15
#> Columns: 4
#> $ GPA           <dbl> 3.897, 3.885, 3.778, 2.540, 3.028, 3.865, 2.962, 3.961, …
#> $ ACT_Score     <dbl> 21, 14, 28, 22, 21, 31, 32, 27, 29, 26, 24, 30, 24, 24, …
#> $ fitted_GPA    <df[,1]> <data.frame[15 x 1]>
#> $ residuals_GPA <df[,1]> <data.frame[15 x 1]>

GPA_lm = lm(formula = GPA ~ ACT_Score, data = ch_1_exer_119_GPA)
fitted_GPA = coef(GPA_lm)[[1]] + coef(GPA_lm)[[2]]*ch_1_exer_119_GPA[,2]   # created vector of fitted values
ch_1_exer_119_GPA$fitted_GPA = fitted_GPA
glimpse(ch_1_exer_119_GPA)
#> Rows: 15
#> Columns: 4
#> $ GPA           <dbl> 3.897, 3.885, 3.778, 2.540, 3.028, 3.865, 2.962, 3.961, …
#> $ ACT_Score     <dbl> 21, 14, 28, 22, 21, 31, 32, 27, 29, 26, 24, 30, 24, 24, …
#> $ fitted_GPA    <df[,1]> <data.frame[15 x 1]>
#> $ residuals_GPA <df[,1]> <data.frame[15 x 1]>
ch_1_exer_119_GPA
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#>      GPA ACT_Score fitted_GPA$ACT_Score residuals_GPA$ACT_Score
#>    <dbl>     <dbl>                <dbl>                   <dbl>
#>  1  3.90        21                 3.32                  0.968 
#>  2  3.88        14                 3.53                  1.23  
#>  3  3.78        28                 3.12                  0.577 
#>  4  2.54        22                 3.29                 -0.428 
#>  5  3.03        21                 3.32                  0.0986
#>  6  3.86        31                 3.03                  0.547 
#>  7  2.96        32                 3.00                 -0.395 
#>  8  3.96        27                 3.15                  0.799 
#>  9  0.5         29                 3.09                 -2.74  
#> 10  3.18        26                 3.18                  0.0544
#> 11  3.31        24                 3.24                  0.264 
#> 12  3.54        30                 3.06                  0.259 
#> 13  3.08        24                 3.24                  0.0371
#> 14  3.01        24                 3.24                 -0.0329
#> 15  3.24        33                 2.97                 -0.150
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: When I create the `fitted_GPA` using the provided data, I get a vector as a result, not a data.frame. From the code provided by the OP, it's not clear what is going on. There may be some intermediate steps that we've not been told about?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik the only step I left out was reading the data set into R.

Comment: glad it solved it @dc3rd. @RomanLuštrik, I added a full reprex. Apparently when printing the data.frame (or df_tbl) to console, it says the variable is `<dbl>`, but `glimpse()` says otherwise. Is that also what you've got?

Comment: I almost religiously load up the tidyverse packages and up to this point in my journey have never paid any mind to the `reprex` package. This was a more informative session than I anticipated. Probably won't be able to master it any time soon, but at least I have awareness of it now. :)

Comment: Any action that can be described as "religious" should make you pause and rethink your actions. :) I have yet to understand why anyone would want to load 20 packages that would not necessarily be used at all. It increases load time and the masking...

Comment: Just revisiting this now @RomanLuštrik . I appreciate the small nugget of wisdom.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This is your data

```
> str(xy)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   15 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ GPA          : num  3.9 3.88 3.78 2.54 3.03 ...
 $ ACT_Score    : num  21 14 28 22 21 31 32 27 29 26 ...
 $ fitted_GPA   :'data.frame':  15 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ ACT_Score: num  2.93 2.66 3.2 2.97 2.93 ...
 $ residuals_GPA:'data.frame':  15 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ ACT_Score: num  0.9676 1.2274 0.5768 -0.4282 0.0986 ...
```

Notice that `fitted_GPA` is a data.frame added inside a data.frame. This works because a data.frame is just a special list and as you know, you can have a list of lists... Anyway, when I run

```
GPA_lm <- lm(formula = GPA ~ ACT_Score, data = xy)
fitted_GPA <- coef(GPA_lm)[[1]] + coef(GPA_lm)[[2]] * xy[, 2] 

xy$fitted_GPA <- fitted_GPA
```

I get a nice clean result

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   15 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ GPA          : num  3.9 3.88 3.78 2.54 3.03 ...
 $ ACT_Score    : num  21 14 28 22 21 31 32 27 29 26 ...
 $ fitted_GPA   : num  3.32 3.53 3.12 3.29 3.32 ...
 $ residuals_GPA:'data.frame':  15 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ ACT_Score: num  0.9676 1.2274 0.5768 -0.4282 0.0986 ...

> typeof(xy$fitted_GPA)
[1] "double"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Tibble` allow the creation of list columns. As mentioned before, a data.frame is just a special kind of list. For example, to store an `lm` object inside of a tibble we could do this:

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse

data.frame(values = list(lm(cyl ~ hwy, mpg))) %>%
  `[`(1, 1, 1)
#> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors): cannot coerce class '"lm"' to a data.frame

#but this will work 

tibble(values = list(lm(cyl ~ hwy, mpg))) %T>%
  print() %>% 
  `[`(1, 1, 1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   values
#>   <list>
#> 1 <lm>
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = cyl ~ hwy, data = mpg)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          hwy  
#>     10.7223      -0.2062
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

In this particular case we can use `unnest()` to expand the dataframe.

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse

glimpse(ch_1_exer_119_GPA)
#> Rows: 15
#> Columns: 4
#> $ GPA           <dbl> 3.897, 3.885, 3.778, 2.540, 3.028, 3.865, 2.962, 3.961, …
#> $ ACT_Score     <dbl> 21, 14, 28, 22, 21, 31, 32, 27, 29, 26, 24, 30, 24, 24, …
#> $ fitted_GPA    <df[,1]> <data.frame[15 x 1]>
#> $ residuals_GPA <df[,1]> <data.frame[15 x 1]>

unnest(ch_1_exer_119_GPA, c(fitted_GPA, residuals_GPA)) %T>%
  print() %>% 
  glimpse()
#> # A tibble: 225 x 4
#>      GPA ACT_Score fitted_GPA residuals_GPA
#>    <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1  3.90        21       2.93        0.968 
#>  2  3.90        21       2.66        1.23  
#>  3  3.90        21       3.20        0.577 
#>  4  3.90        21       2.97       -0.428 
#>  5  3.90        21       2.93        0.0986
#>  6  3.90        21       3.32        0.547 
#>  7  3.90        21       3.36       -0.395 
#>  8  3.90        21       3.16        0.799 
#>  9  3.90        21       3.24       -2.74  
#> 10  3.90        21       3.12        0.0544
#> # … with 215 more rows
#> Rows: 225
#> Columns: 4
#> $ GPA           <dbl> 3.897, 3.897, 3.897, 3.897, 3.897, 3.897, 3.897, 3.897, …
#> $ ACT_Score     <dbl> 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, …
#> $ fitted_GPA    <dbl> 2.929419, 2.657629, 3.201209, 2.968246, 2.929419, 3.3176…
#> $ residuals_GPA <dbl> 0.96758105, 1.22737094, 0.57679116, -0.42824608, 0.09858…
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>